# Flask - Send different function parameter based on button click without refreshing

Tags: python, flask

I am looking for a way to passthrough the value of the button I pressed to a function so based on the button click I want the same function to run but with a different value being passed into it.

index.html

```
<div class='container'>
    <h3>Test</h3>
        <form >
          <a href=# id=clest1><button class='btn btn-default'>Mercury</button></a>
          <a href=# id=clest2><button class='btn btn-default'>Moon</button></a>
          <a href=# id=clest3><button class='btn btn-default'>Mars</button></a>
          <a href=# id=clest4><button class='btn btn-default'>Jupiter</button></a>
          <a href=# id=clest5><button class='btn btn-default'>Saturn</button></a>
          <a href=# id=clest6><button class='btn btn-default'>Uranus</button></a>
          <a href=# id=clest7><button class='btn btn-default'>Neptune</button></a>
      </form>
</div
```

Based on which ever of these buttons are clicked I would like for it to be route to the same function, and for that function to call another function with the value from the pressed button being passed through
webApp.py

```
@app.route('/planetChoice')
def planetChoice():
    value = None
    if clest1:
        value = 'Mercury'
    elif clest2:
        value = 'Moon'
    elif clest3:
        value = 'Mars'
    elif clest4:
        value = 'Jupiter'
    elif clest5:
        value = 'Saturn'
    elif clest6:
        value = 'Uranus'
    elif clest7:
        value = "Neptune"

    
    onPub(value)

    return render_template('/index.html')
```

I would like for the onPub function to have as its parameter the value of the button I pressed, is there anyway to do this while also not refreshing the page?

I have tried using post but that caused the page to refresh which is something I am trying to avoid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. maybe you can utilize python's request module. Recognize the content of the request coming from the front end.
2. If you need to not refresh the page. Then you need to create an ajax request. Like the following.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Flask SPA Form</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="name-input">
    <button id="submit-button">Submit</button>

    <script>
        (function() {("#submit-button").click(function() {
                var name = ("#name-input").val();.ajax({
                    url: "/submit",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: { name: name },
                    success: function(response) {
                        alert("Form submitted successfully!");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that this is just a sample code. It cannot be used directly on your project

In this example, the jQuery library is introduced to simplify the handling of Ajax requests. On clicking the submit button, the JavaScript code takes the value in the input box and sends the form data to the server's /submit route via an Ajax request.